# How to put 2 different Submit Buttons in a form (with CI)?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, paypal

I have a form where I want the user to choose 2 different way to checkout :

Let say that the user enters his informations like his address, name and credit info.
Using Paypal Pro, at the end, I want him to be able to choose whether or not he wants to checkout through paypal or through direct payment ... that would lead to a second form.

By the way, with CodeIgnieter, when following a form with another one, I got the validation process of the second one that always run, I mean when I come from the first form to the second one, in the second form I will see my error messages appears, for each field even if the user didn't try to submit yet. Is there a way to avoid this bug ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edited: see end of the answer

You should do it as you would normally:

View:

```
<form method="post" action="mysite.com/submit">
    <input type="text" name="name1">
    <input type="text" name="name2">
    <input type="text" name="name3">

    <input type="submit" name="sbm" value="Direct">
    <input type="submit" name="sbm" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

In PHP (controller probably):

```
if($this->input->post('sbm') == "PayPal") { 
    // do something with PayPal
} else {
    // do something with direct payment
}
```

Edited: If you would like the caption of the button (visible text) to differ from the value, use `<button>` element instead of the `<input type="submit">`:

```
<button name="payment_type" value="paypal" type="submit">I want to pay with PayPal</button>
<button name="payment_type" value="direct" type="submit">Or should I go with Direct Payment?</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, any Idea about the bug ? without considering CI, in PHP, if you have 2 forms one after another, won't you have any problem with the validation process of the second one ? It seems like when you click on submit the first form, it tries to submit the second form at the same time even if its not pop up yet. Then CI shows me the errors messages ...

Comment: Can't say much without inspecting your code. Are your forms named differently? Are you sure they do not intersect? (It should be `<form></form><form></form>`, not `<form><form></form></form>`.

Comment: yeah, its on 2 different functions in the controller, 2 different views. I'll edit y post by tomrrow morning :) need to get some sleep !

Comment: As it's a different question, you better make a new one.

Comment: There is absolutely no need for every button to have the same `name`... _IMO, a bad practice_.  Give each button a unique `name` and `if ($this->input->post('unique_name')) { ...`  will work perfectly well.

Comment: @Sparky why would that be a bad practice? It's a correct way to determine the type of submission, just like radio buttons have the same `name` but different values. In case there would be 100 different options to checkout, you would make 100 checks in PHP?

Comment: `radio` buttons share the same `name` because the selection from a group of `radio` buttons represent a single piece of data.  There is no good reason for the submit buttons to share the same `name` at all.  Like I explained in my comment, `if ($this->input->post('unique_button_name')) { ...` works perfectly well to test which `submit` button was used.

Answer (score 1):

Use some conditions for applying the validation rules.

```
if(isPayPalPro())
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules(....);
}else
{
    //validation credit card payment
}
```

use some condition instead of isPayPalPro().

Answer (score 1):

An alternative i personally like more is to name every submit button differently, like so:

```
<form method="post" action="mysite.com/submit">
    <input type="text" name="name1">
    <input type="text" name="name2">
    <input type="text" name="name3">

    <input type="submit" name="direct" value="Direct">
    <input type="submit" name="paypal" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Then check which value was sent:

```
if($this->input->post('direct')){
    //Direct button was pressed
}
if($this->input->post('paypal')){
    //Paypal button was pressed
}
```