# two different submit button on a form codeigniter acting weird

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have two buttons on one submit form but when I post the submit button it returns nothing;"ABOUT THE BUTTON"; the other data is retrieved WELL.

I have been using different names for the submit button but nothing works.. Could someone help me? thank you.
The FORM data is retrieved well but not the submit button value? i need the value to differ the condition

controller: admin.php

```
        function submit_unitgroupwd(){
        $this->access_chk(); //CHECK USER ACCESS

    $sbm=$this->input->post('sbm'); // returns NOTHING
   echo $_POST["sbm"]; // returns undefined index sbm
   echo $_POST['sbm']; // returns undefined index sbm
var_dump($_POST); // returns all the post data bt the submit button

 //echo var_dump($this->input->post("sbm"));
exit();

if($this->input->post('sbm') == "Update") { 
// do update
} else {
// do delete
}

}
```

view:

```
 echo "<form action=".site_url("admin/submit_unitgroupwd")." method=post id=form>"; 
echo "<div style='float:left;color:red;' id='res'></div>";
?><?php 
foreach($q1->result_array() as $r1){
$bankname= substr($r1["bank"],0,3);
//echo $bankname;


echo "<input type=hidden name=dgroup value='".$dgroup."'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=20% colspan=3 style='font-size: 16px;'>".strtoupper($r1["bank"])."</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td width=100>".$group_[0]."</td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name='$bankname-utama' value='".str_replace(" ","",$r1["utama"])."' style='width: 100%;'></td>";

if ($r1["bank"] == 'ALL'){
    echo "<td rowspan='1'><br><input type='checkbox' name='cek[]' id='cek[]' value='$bankname' ></td>";

    echo "<input type=hidden name=_code$bankname value='".$r1["bank"]."'>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
    continue;
}

echo "<td rowspan=".($dgroup + 1)."><br><input type='checkbox' name='cek[]' id='cek[]' value='$bankname' ><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>";
echo "<input type=hidden name=_code$bankname value='".$r1["bank"]."'>";

echo "</tr>";

$_alp = "a";
for ($_g=0; $_g<$dgroup; $_g++){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width=100>".$group_[($_g + 1)]."</td>";
    echo "<td width=80%><input type=text name='$bankname-wd$_alp' value='".str_replace(" ","",$r1["wd$_alp"])."' style='width: 100%;'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $_alp++;
echo "</tr>";

}
}
?>
>
<input type="submit" class="button" value='Update' name="sbm"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" value='Delete' name="sbm"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use only the

```
 <input type="submit" class="button" value='Update' name="sbm"/>
```

and use an anchor for the delete action,

```
echo "<a href ='controller_delete/$item_id' class='button'>Delete</a>
```

since you normally wont need other inputs on the delete action if you get my point.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not completely clear on your description of the problem, but you can't name both submit buttons the same.

You seem to think that push one or the other button will only submit THAT button's value, but in fact the second one is always submitted, because it is the last on the form.

So change your button names to "update" & "delete", and then you can check with

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))....
```

for example.

However, you might want to look around the internet for some cleaner examples of how to code what you are after.

Comment: Im sorry but I had successfully did this in the other form using CI framework. Please look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391007/how-to-put-2-different-submit-buttons-in-a-form-with-ci

Comment: I stand corrected - I did not think that would work, and honestly am not sure I trust it. In any case, your form is submitting to admin/submit_unitgroupwd but your controller is admin/submit_withdraw_admin, so let's clean up your post above and check things like that before continuing

Comment: I apologized. I was mistakenly copying from another function in the controller. i will try your idea once I got back on my desk. Thank you Jeff. :)

Comment: @xyonme, regardless of the other accepted answer, I would never use the same `name` attribute on two totally different `input` elements.  This answer by jmadsen is clearly more solid.

Comment: Hi @Sparky I have tried jmadsen idea but its not retrieving the POST value of the submit button . The result is above. I dont know why its not posting. Im using Dimitri's solution below.. Thank you. :)

Comment: I mean the result is undefined index if i use $_POST. And it is empty if i use $this->input ->post

Comment: @xyonme, my `form` has several `submit` buttons, each with its own `name`.  My "cancel" button has `name="cancel"` and this works perfectly:  `if ($this->input->post('cancel')) { ...`

Comment: @sparky I have tried jmadsen code in my other form which contains two buttons , it works well too but not in this current form. I'm going to apply the idea on the other forms. Thank you. :)

Comment: @xyonme, if it works for me and it works for you on your other form, then you must have done something wrong on this form.